# it[imageView, uri, placeHolder] = tag ,what this mean?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, syntax

when I read the source code of MaterialDrawerKt library,there are some code I dont understand?who can explain for me?thanks

```
/**
    * @param imageView
    * @param uri
    * @param tag
    * @return false if not consumed
    */
   open fun setImage(imageView: ImageView, uri: Uri, tag: String?): Boolean {
       // If we do not handle this protocol we keep the original behavior
       return if (mHandleAllProtocols || uri.scheme in mHandledProtocols) {
           imageLoader?.let {
               val placeHolder = it.placeholder(imageView.context, tag)
               it[imageView, uri, placeHolder] = tag
           }
           true
       } else false
   }
```

who can explain this code ?it[imageView, uri, placeHolder] = tag

Comment: When you see brackets like that, it is equivalent to calling a function called `get()` or `set()` with those parameters, so that code is the same as `it.set(imageView,  uri, placeholder, tag)`

Comment: yes，you are right. you solve my question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [indexed access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator)

(copied from the link):

| Expression | Translated to |
| --- | --- |
| a[i] | a.get(i) |
| a[i, j] | a.get(i, j) |
| a[i_1, ..., i_n] | a.get(i_1, ..., i_n) |
| a[i] = b | a.set(i, b) |
| a[i, j] = b | a.set(i, j, b) |
| a[i_1, ..., i_n] = b | a.set(i_1, ..., i_n, b) |

Square brackets are translated to calls to get and set with appropriate numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin when you see `[]` brackets that impiles java methods `get()` or `set()`.

So here `it[imageView, uri, placeHolder] = tag` could be equivalent to
`it.set(imageView,  uri, placeholder, tag)`